# Kotlin how to make sure that generic parameter is superclass of receiver class

Tags: generics, reflection, kotlin

I tried to implement quick field accessor function, and also wanted to make sure, that specified class (real owner of the field) is superclass of the receiver type, thus I wrote it as following:

```
inline fun <A : B, reified B: Any> A.getProperty (name: String): Any {
    return B::class.java.getDeclaredField(name).apply { isAccessible = true }.get(this)
}
```

But this makes me pointlessly write receiver type during invocation:

```
// in SubClass
getProperty<SubClass, BaseClass>("fieldThatIsInBaseClass")
```

In case when field is defined in current class, it doesn't even need parameters to my surprise:

```
// in BaseClass
getProperty("fieldThatIsInBaseClass")
```

I also tried to add field type parameter to the function, but that breaks code above, and in every case all parameters have to be specified:

```
inline fun <A : B, reified B: Any, T> A.getProperty (name: String): T {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return B::class.java.getDeclaredField(name).apply { isAccessible = true }.get(this) as T
}
```

And example how this breaks things:

```
// in a class Example which declares the field
getProperty<Example, Example, Int>("someIntField")
```

The ideal syntax in a class that defines field should be:

```
getProperty<Int>("someIntField")
```

And for class that extends some base class:

```
getProperty<BaseClass, Int>("fieldThatIsInBaseClass")
```

Is something like that possible?

Comment: You have "subclass" in the title and "superclass" in the question, second is probably correct.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov thanks, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need `A` at all? If you replace it with `B`:

```
inline fun <reified B: Any> B.getProperty (name: String): Any {
    return B::class.java.getDeclaredField(name).apply { isAccessible = true }.get(this)
}
```

it'll also accept any subtypes of `B`.

Comment: I'm afraid this throws `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException` if field is not defined in `B`. That's the problem with reflection. For `getDeclaredField`, class that defined the field must be used. To fix this we could have used `getField`, but this doesn't find `private` and `protected` fields, which are the whole point of that example.

Comment: "I'm afraid this throws java.lang.NoSuchFieldException if field is not defined in B." Then so will your original code, no? You are still supposed to use it as `aSubClassInstance.getProperty<BaseClass>(...)`.

Comment: No, if I call it (that's within SubClass): 
`getProperty<SubClass, BaseClass>("fieldThatIsInBaseClass")`
That will translate into
`BaseClass::class.java.getDeclaredField("fieldThatIsInBaseClass").apply { isAccessible = true }.get(this)`, so it's valid. I tested original code and it works, but the syntax is unnecessarily verbose

Comment: Right, and with this you call it as `getProperty<BaseClass>("fieldThatIsInBaseClass")` and it translates into exactly the same thing.

Comment: Ops... ok convinced me :)